# how to show only the last 4 numbers in a text box in access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a field with a phone number how do i make another text box the should have the same number but only the last 4 number from the phone number

Answer (score 2):

textboxShortPhone.value = right(textboxPhone,4)